# attributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

При запуске скрипта

```
import smtplib
import re
import time


def send_mail(email, passwd, receivers, subject, text, sender):
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.yandex.ru", 465)
    server.login(email, passwd)
    for receiver in receivers:
        msg = "\r\n".join([ \
            "From: {}".format(sender), \
            "To: {}".format(receiver), \
            "Subject: {}".format(subject), \
            "", \
            "{}".format(text) \
            ])
        server.sendmail(email, receiver, msg)
        print('Send message to: %s' % receiver)
        time.sleep(1)
    server.quit()

with open('email.txt', 'r') as fr:
    txt = fr.read()
    email = re.search(r'.*?@yandex\.ru', txt).group(0)
    passwd = txt[len(email) + 1:]

with open('receivers.txt', 'r') as fr:
    receivers = []
    for mail in fr:
        receivers.append(mail)

    receivers = [rec.rstrip() for rec in receivers]

with open('message.txt', 'r') as fr:
    message = fr.read()

print('Enter a message subject:')
subject = input()
print('Eneter a message sender:')
sender = input()
send_mail(email, passwd, receivers, subject, message, sender)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>: 
File "main.py",line 24,in <module> 
email = re.search(r'.*?@yandex\.ru', txt).group(0) 
attributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки в том, что `re.search` не нашел строку по указанному шаблону и вернул `None`, а после этого у `None` вызвали атрибут `group`, что и привело к ошибке.

Мини пример получения ошибки:

```
# Поиск цифр в строке
print(re.search(r'\d', 'abc'))  # None
```

Сделайте проверку, например:

```
with open('email.txt', 'r') as fr:
    txt = fr.read()
    match = re.search(r'.*?@yandex\.ru', txt)
    if match:
        email = match.group(0)
        passwd = txt[len(email) + 1:]
```

---

**PS.**

Если работа скрипта при отсутствии почты/пароля невозможна, то добавьте отображение ошибки и прерывание скрипта, например:

```
    ...

    if match:
        email = match.group(0)
        passwd = txt[len(email) + 1:]
    else:
        print("[-] Not found email!")
        quit()
```